Stopping R shiny app before it ran out of memory
I'm designing a R shiny application, where the user can upload a table, select feature from this table and run a random forest using ranger package. Depending on the table size, sometimes the application crashes and the logs display "Killed" (which I understand is an out of memory issue).
I would like to prevent the shiny app to crash, stopping it automatically when it's gonna run out of memory.
I tried to use the try function or even running my model as a background job using r_bg function from callR package but still the app will crash.
Is there any way to prevent it (I'd rather have a message saying the model cannot be run rather than the app crashing)?
Thank you

You should program and test this outside of Shiny. Use tryCatch or similar to catch the error. But part of this depends on whether the ranger package is able to stop itself from crashing your whole computer. You can only catch R errors, not things that crash everything.

You could try monitoring the memory consumption and kill the background process before it is out of memory. Please see my related answer here.

@MichaelDewar, I think you're right, this depends on the ranger package, maybe this is what I should be investigating.

Thank you @ismirsehregal for the example of memory monitoring. However I feel it's a bit more complicated as once the ranger function is called, the app should stop automatically.
